# Fastest way to copy a nested list

Tags: c#, list, copy, nested

I have a three dimensional list. The outer list represents how many class periods there are. The next inner list represents how many students there are (the positions in the list are the students unique ids). The final list is the course ids the student is taking that period.

What is the fastest way I can copy this list?

I tried

```
a.var = var.Select(x => x.ToList()).ToList().ToList();
```

That does not work though. The following is what I am using, but I am sure there is a much cleaner and faster way and I would like to learn how.

```
foreach (PERIOD period in periods)
{
  a.var.Add(new List<List<int>>());

  for (int student = 0; student < students.Count + 1; student++)
     a.var[IntFromEnum(period)].Add(new List<int>());

  foreach (Course course in periods[IntFromEnum(period)])
  {
     foreach (int student in course.students)
       a.var[IntFromEnum(period)][student] = new List<int>(var[IntFromEnum(period)][student])
  }
}
```

Comment: Though not a solution to you problem, maybe you should be using a list of objects rather than primitives.

Comment: You can use parallel foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't experiment on your type, but assuming your `periods` collection looks like this

```
List<List<List<int>>> p;
```

then you can do some inner `Select`s to copy. Something like this:

```
var a = p.Select(x => new List<List<int>>(x.Select(y => new List<int>(y)))).ToList();
```

or a cleaner:

```
var a = p.Select(x => x.Select(y => y.ToList()).ToList()).ToList();
```

Not necessarily the fastest, but pretty straightforward with code.

Comment: That is what I was looking forward. Now that I see it, it makes sense.